# How to filter foreign key objects in django queries?

Tags: django, django-models, one-to-many, django-orm

I have two models, one related to other by `foreign key` like this

```
class CapturedPrescriptionModel(ColModel):
    p_id = models.IntegerField()
    p_age = models.IntegerField()
    p_gender = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    p_care_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    bacteria_id = models.ForeignKey(BacteriaListModel, 
              on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

class SuggestedAntibioticsModel(ColModel):
    prescription_id = models.ForeignKey(CapturedPrescriptionModel, 
                  related_name='antibiotics', 
                   on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cat_ids = models.TextField()
    flag = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Now I want all the `prescriptions` with `suggested antibiotics` where `flag=1`

I have tried with `CapturedPrescriptionModel.objects.filter(antibiotics__flag=1)` but that filter the prescriptions not the list of antibiotics in the queryset.

```
 [
    {
    "id": 7,
    "p_id": 0,
    "p_age": 19,
    "p_gender": "Male",
    "p_care_type": "ICU",
    "bacteria_id": null,
    "antibiotics": [
        {
            "id": 188,
            "cat_ids": "[]",
            "flag": 0,
            "antibiotic_id_id": 87,
            "prescription_id_id": 7
        },
        {
            "id": 187,
            "cat_ids": "[]",
            "flag": 1,
            "antibiotic_id_id": 112,
            "prescription_id_id": 7
        },
      ......
      ]
}
....
]
```

My expected result will be like this

```
    [
        {
        "id": 7,
        "p_id": 0,
        "p_age": 19,
        "p_gender": "Male",
        "p_care_type": "ICU",
        "bacteria_id": null,
        "antibiotics": [
            {
                "id": 187,
                "cat_ids": "[]",
                "flag": 1,
                "antibiotic_id_id": 112,
                "prescription_id_id": 7
            }
          ]
}
....
]
```

Comment: Do you want all prescriptions (even those without `antibiotics__flag=1`), but the `antibiotics` set should contain only those with `flag=1`?

Comment: Yes, for those prescription for which any `antibiotics__flag=1` does not suffice should be a empty list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a filtered `Prefetch` if you want to filter the related objects only, not the main objects:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

CapturedPrescriptionModel.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch(
    'antibiotics',
    queryset=SuggestedAntibioticsModel.objects.filter(flag=1)
)
```

You then have to make sure that `antibiotics` on the individual prescription objects is only accessed with `prescription.antibiotics.all()`, otherwise the prefetch is not used and you'll get all antibiotics again.

Answer (score 0):

Collect all Prescriptions:

```py
prescriptions = CapturedPrescriptionModel.objects.all()

for prescription in prescriptions:
    prescription.antibiotics = prescription.antibiotics.filter(flag=1)

# at this time presciptions should be prepared, just make sure to not save them...
```

You could also extend your model to have a property for that list.

```py
class CapturedPrescriptionModel(ColModel):
    p_id = models.IntegerField()
    p_age = models.IntegerField()
    p_gender = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    p_care_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    bacteria_id = models.ForeignKey(BacteriaListModel, 
              on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    @property
    def flagged_antibiotics(self):
        try:
            return self.antibiotics.filter(flag=1)
        except Exception:
            return []

class SuggestedAntibioticsModel(ColModel):
    prescription_id = models.ForeignKey(CapturedPrescriptionModel, 
                  related_name='antibiotics', 
                   on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cat_ids = models.TextField()
    flag = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Something like this would be my first take on that